# P4V not connecting to my DigitalOcean Droplet when setting up a Perforce Server

Tags: perforce, digital-ocean, p4v

I'm trying to set up a Perforce Server using a Droplet from DigitalOcean and connect to it via P4V.

I was following this tutorial https://allarsblog.com/2014/09/25/setup-perforce-digital/ which I was originally led to by an Unreal Engine official YouTube tutorial. When I got to the part where I was supposed to connect via P4V I got the following error:

Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
TCP connect to [Droplet IP Address]:1666 failed.
connect: [Droplet IP Address]:1666: WSAECONNREFUSED

I posted on the DigitalOcean forum and they suggested I try to set the P4PORT then verify it with p4 info, but the p4 info command only yields the following:

Perforce client error:
      Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
      TCP connect to devel:1666 failed.
      No such host is known.

Since it said no such host is known, I tried using the direct IP Address in the place of devel, and that only returned the same result but it also said connect: [IP Address]:1666: WSAECONNREFUSED.

I can ping the IP Address just fine. Connecting via puTTY (port 22) does not seem to be an issue. I'm using Windows 10, I heard Firewalls could produce this problem but even if I disable my Firewall I get the same errors.

This is my first time doing this, so I may have made a beginners mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It sure sounds like a firewall issue. `ping` uses a different network protocol, and putty connects to a different network port, so neither of them are really testing whether you have resolved the firewall problem or not. Can you tell putty to try connecting on port 1666 and see what happens? Also, since you're setting up both a server and a client, you probably want to learn how to debug this from the server side first, before you try to debug it from the client side. That is, make sure your server is actually up and running before you worry about network issues.

Comment: Would there be a firewall up on my server side from DigitalOcean? I guess that is something I need to look into. I'll also have to find how I can check to see how to get my server up and running without P4V. I'm lost there. Time to start Googling keywords.

Comment: Found my answer in another Forum: 
Fire up PuTTY and log in as “root”
Type “p4d” from the command line (If you don’t see it, it should be located in “/usr/local/bin”)

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer in another Forum: Fire up PuTTY and log in as “root” Type “p4d” from the command line (If you don’t see it, it should be located in “/usr/local/bin”)

Comment: Ah, so you hadn't actually *started* the server, just installed the software. There are ways to automatically start the server, but it sounds like you're unblocked for now, good to hear!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

To clear the " WSAECONREFUSED " error  we put Server:[DigitalOcean ServerIP]:1666 and clicked the "New" button for user.

We were prompted with a new error -> WSAETIMEDOUT
to solve this we had to open the 1666 port on the server so we opened the up and down 1666 using these commands.

```sh
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1666 --syn -j ACCEPT
```

&

```sh
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 1666 -j ACCEPT
```